# Changing the selected Menu items class across pages

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-3, xhtml, razor

For my website project I am using ASP.NET MVC "Razor". Learning as I go.

I have 5 or 6 pages on my site, and one page that is on another site.  I want users to feel like they are using the same site for all.

There is a typical HTML menu for the pages which follows the standard pattern of using a XHTML unordered list and CSS to layout:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="selected"><a href="@Href("~/")">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://ceklog.kindel.com">cek.log</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Href("~/Services")">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Href("~/Charlie")">Charlie's Stuff</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Href("~/Contact.cshtml")">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Elsewhere on SO I found questions similar to mine, where people wanted to track the selected menu item, but within a dynamic page. For example:

[Javascript Changing the selected Menu items class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968763/javascript-changing-the-selected-menu-items-class)

But this approach won't work in my case because in my case the user is not changing a selection on one page, but navigating to another page completely.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...and I figured it out.

I used Razor to implement this on the server side.

First I implemented a function on my `_SiteLayout.cshtml` page (the template all pages use):

```
@functions {
    public string Selected(string PageTitle) {
       if (Page.Title == PageTitle)
          return "selected";
        else
          return "";
    }
}
```

Then I used this function in my list:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="@Selected("Home")"><a href="@Href("~/")">Home</a></li>
    <li class="@Selected("cek.log")"><a href="http://ceklog.kindel.com">cek.log</a></li>
    <li class="@Selected("Services")"><a href="@Href("~/Services")">Services</a></li>
    <li class="@Selected("Charlie's Stuff")"><a href="@Href("~/Charlie")">Charlie's Stuff</a></li>
    <li class="@Selected("Contact")"><a href="@Href("~/Contact.cshtml")">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Works perfectly.  On my external page, I just hand-coded it since it's based on Wordpress and not Razor.